# Rails5 tinymce-rails-imageupload / uploaded picture is not showing in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm making blog site with Blog Model and User Model. I use carrierwave, TinyMCE, tinymce-rails-imageupload to achive blog with WISYWIG. Basically i followed this site to upload picture in development: [Use tinymce-rails & tinymce-rails-imageupload with carrierwave & fog](http://gist.github.com/dannyvassallo/f0fff53bfd88114ec4e7)

After i create new blog post, uploading picture and text , i can see the text and picture in show page (blogs/show.html.erb). However, when i try to move to edit page(blogs/edit.html.erb), i can only see the text(uploaded picture is not showing). I want to show picture and text in edit page so i can edit the blog page properly. How can i fix this?

*i deleted turbolinks in Application.js

**Blog.rb**:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord 
   mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
   validates :text, presence: true, length: { maximum:140}
   validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20}
end
```

**Routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :blogs
 post '/tinymce_assets', to: 'blogs#upload_image'
end
```

**Blogs/edit.html.erb**:

```
<%= render 'form', blog: @blog %>
<%= link_to 'Back', blogs_path %>
```

**Blogs/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for(blog) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>

   <%= f.label :text %>
   <%= f.text_area :text, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 100,
   :cols => 120 %>
   <%= tinymce :text_css => asset_path('application.css')%>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Blogs/show.html.erb**:

```
  <%= @blog.title %>

  <%= sanitize @blog.text, tags: %w(h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 ul ol li p a img 
  table tr td em br strong),  attributes:  %w(id class href src) %>

  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(@blog) %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', blogs_path %>
```

**Blogs_controller.rb**:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

   respond_to :json

   def new
     @blog = Blog.new
   end

   def create
     @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

     if @blog.save
     redirect_to @blog
     else
     render 'new'
     end
   end

   def show
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
   end

   def index
     @blogs = Blog.all
   end

   def edit
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
     if @blog.update(blog_params)
     redirect_to @blog
     else
     render 'edit'
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
     @blog.destroy
     redirect_to blogs_path
   end

   def upload_image 
     image = Blog.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint )
      render json: {
        image: {
          url: image.file.url
        }
      }, content_type: "text/html"
    end

    private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :text, :file, :hint, :alt)
    end
end
```

**Image_uploader.rb**:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   storage :file

   def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

   def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
end
```

**Application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require tinymce
```

**Layouts/Application.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title))%></title> 
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-
     turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
     'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
   </head>
  <body>
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
   <%= tinymce_assets %> 
   <div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
   <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
   </div>
   <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was due to relative url is set to true.
In my view( _form.html.erb), I added <%= tinymce :relative_urls => false %> this solved the problem. Thanks.